# Ruby - remove pattern from string

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a string pattern that, as an example, looks like this:

```
WBA - Skinny Joe vs. Hefty Hal
```

I want to truncate the pattern "WBA - " from the string and return just "Skinny Joe vs. Hefty Hal".

Comment: Any combo of letters and numbers can precede the "-".

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Assuming that the "WBA" spot will be a sequence of any letter or number, followed by a space, dash, and space:

```
str = "WBA - Skinny Joe vs. Hefty Hal"
str.sub /^\w+\s-\s/, ''
```

By the way — [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) is a great tool for testing regular expressions like these.

Answer (score 17):

If you need a more complex string replacement, you can look into writing a more sophisticated regular expression. Otherwise:

**Keep it simple!** If you only need to remove `"WBA - "` from the beginning of the string, use `String#sub`.

```rb
s = "WBA - Skinny Joe vs. Hefty Hal"
puts s.sub(/^WBA - /, '')
# => Skinny Joe vs. Hefty Hal
```

Comment: ProTip™: Use `gsub` if you want to replace _ALL_ occurrences.

Answer (score 6):

You can also remove the first occurrence of a pattern with the following snippet:

```
s[/^WBA - /] = ''
```