# How to exclude special characters in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra

I am new to ruby and looking for a solution where I wanted to remove search a lines in a file with specific string and that string does not contains special characters.
eg:

```html
irb(main):005:0> File.readlines("test.sh").select {|line| line =~ /Passphr|passphrs/}
=> ["passphrs=mw4test\n", "Passphrase=$passphrs\n", "Passphrase=$passphrs\n"]
```

I want ignore the text which is having "=$" as combination and desire output should be as:
passphrs=mw4test

Please suggest?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby - remove pattern from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920285/ruby-remove-pattern-from-string)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just add a second condition to your `select` block:

```
File
  .readlines("test.sh")
  .select { |line| line =~ /Passphr|passphrs/ && !line.include?('=$') }
```